# Get the list of same name element from a list in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements and I want to have a function that takes that list, processes it and returns me the list of elements that has the same name. How can I do that in Javascript or jquery?

```
[{ ID : 1, Name : "john" , BrandName : "Lg" },
 { ID : 2, Name : "john" , BrandName : "Lg" },
 { ID : 3, Name : "doe" , BrandName : "kenwood" },
 { ID : 4, Name : "peter" , BrandName : "Nokia" },
 { ID : 5, Name : "john" , BrandName : "Lg" }
 { ID : 6, Name : "ethan" , BrandName : "Sony" }
 { ID : 7, Name : "micheal" , BrandName : "Samsung" }];
```

Comment: Your data is wrapped in `()`. Do you mean `[]`, where it is an array?

Comment: also your `=` should be `:`

Comment: you have to give us more information what do you want to do, your question is not clear and your code is not a valid javascript code!

Comment: i have changed it a little bit, i want to a function that returns me a list of same name objects.

Comment: When you say "the same name" do you want to search for a specific name, or find any names which occurs more than once?

Comment: Yeah, your JavaScript is not even syntactically correct. Perhaps before solving the larger problem, why dont you update your code to be proper JS first? For example, a real JS array of objects would be like: [ { id: 1, name: "peter" }]

Comment: @DBS yes i agree to what you same, any names which occurs more than once

Comment: can you give us an Example of possible result?

Comment: @Sheki possibe result could be [{ ID : 1, Name : "john" , BrandName : "Lg" },{ ID : 2, Name : "john" , BrandName : "Lg" },{ ID : 5, Name : "john" , BrandName : "Lg" }]

Comment: @UmerFarooq if "john" name count is 3, "peter" name count is 2, so whats result now?

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL "john" name count is 3 and "peter" name count is 1. I am trying your example

Answer (score 0):

Filter your table to keep elements that are found more than one time in the table :

```
var test = [{ ID : 1, Name : "john" , BrandName : "Lg" },
 { ID : 2, Name : "john" , BrandName : "Lg" },
 { ID : 3, Name : "doe" , BrandName : "kenwood" },
 { ID : 4, Name : "peter" , BrandName : "Nokia" },
 { ID : 5, Name : "john" , BrandName : "Lg" },
 { ID : 6, Name : "ethan" , BrandName : "Sony" },
 { ID : 7, Name : "micheal" , BrandName : "Samsung" }];

test.filter((el) => test.filter(_el => _el.Name === el.Name).length > 1)
// -> 
//    [
//      {ID: 1, Name: "john", BrandName: "Lg"},
//      {ID: 2, Name: "john", BrandName: "Lg"},
//      {ID: 5, Name: "john", BrandName: "Lg"}
//    ]
```